# Registering a console service listener in a Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm having some trouble registering an nsIConsoleListener in my firefox addon. Here is my code:

```
var conSer  = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIConsoleService);

var consoleLis = {
    observe:function( aMessage ){

        conSer.unregisterListener(consoleLis); 

        Components.utils.reportError("observed "+aMessage.message);

    },
    QueryInterface: function (iid) {

        if (!iid.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIConsoleListener) && !iid.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupports)) {

                Components.utils.reportError("NS_ERROR_NO_INTERFACE");

                throw Components.results.NS_ERROR_NO_INTERFACE;

        }

        return this;

    }
};


conSer.registerListener(consoleLis); 

conSer.logStringMessage('this is a test');
```

It seems that no matter what variation of the code I try above, the QueryInterface always seems to throw an error. I had a look through bugzilla to see if there were any outstanding bugs with nsIConsoleListener, but there doesn't seem to be, so I have no idea why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out with help from the people on Mozilla irc:

```
let Cc = Components.classes;
let Ci = Components.interfaces;
let Cu = Components.utils;

Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");

var consoleLis = {
    observe:function( aMessage ){

        dump("observed "+aMessage.message);

        Services.console.unregisterListener(consoleLis); 

    },
    QueryInterface:XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIConsoleListener])
};


Services.console.registerListener(consoleLis); 

Services.console.logStringMessage('this is a test');
```